# Angular 6 DataTables initially display but filter controls does not work

Tags: angular, datatables, angular6, angular-datatables

I am trying to add DataTable to Angular 6. The table initially displays with JSON data. However, when I click on the number of records 10, 25, 50, 100, Column Sorting, Search text, or the pagination controls, all the grid data disappears.

after refresh the page, i get the data again. These are installed in my project.

- npm install jquery --save
- npm install datatables.net --save
- npm install datatables.net-dt --save
- npm install angular-datatables --save
- npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
- npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev

Comment: Please provide a code example,  e.g. at stackblitz